# How to get the sum of each day for the whole month

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

i have a problem getting the sum of each day from the whole month, 
i can already get the sum of the whole month but if i get the sum of each day i keep getting wrong results, the rows are duplicating, it is just weird because when i sum it all i get the right answer, and if i get the sum for each day it is wrong.

here is my table.

`history table`

```
|ID |  from_range   |      to_range       |     price  |      main_id(fk)
1   2019-09-01 00:00:00   2019-09-15 00:00:00       5           1
2   2019-09-16 00:00:00   0000-00-00 00:00:00       10          1
```

`current_usage table`

```
id    main_id(fk)    total_usage   date_created
1         1          10         2019-09-01     
2         1          10         2019-09-01 
3         1          10         2019-09-02 
4         1          10         2019-09-02 
5         1          10         2019-09-05 
6         1          10         2019-09-05 
7         1          10         2019-09-06 
8         1          10         2019-09-06 
9         1          10         2019-09-07 
10        1          10         2019-09-07 
11        1          10         2019-09-15     
12        1          5          2019-09-16 
13        1          5          2019-09-17 
14        1          5          2019-09-18 
15        1          5          2019-09-19 
16        1          5          2019-09-20 
17        1          5          2019-09-25 
18        1          5          2019-09-26 
19        1          5          2019-09-27 
20        1          5          2019-09-30
21        1          5          2019-10-01 
22        1          5          2019-10-01    
23        1          5          2019-10-04 
24        1          5          2019-10-10
```

so in my history_table, I got the date_range from each month, it depends if how many times the user Changes the cost for each day.

so basically

the output should be like this

```
id   price         range_date         total_usage  
1      10   2019-09-01 - 2019-09-15  SUM(total_usage) based on the date range
2      5    2019-09-16 - 2019-09-30  SUM(total_usage) based on the date range
```

here is my current query, this query is for getting the sum for the whole month, but i if edit my query to get the sum of each day, i am having a duplicate entry and keep getting the wrong results. i already tried to group it by Day. but it is still wrong.

```
SELECT SUM(total_usage) FROM (SELECT 
  p.id, 
  p.price, 
  DATE(p.from_range) AS first_range, 
  DATE(IF(p.to_range = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY('2019-09-01'),INTERVAL 10 DAY)) AS second_range,
  (c.total_usage)*p.price AS total_usage
FROM history AS p
INNER JOIN current_usage AS c
        ON c.main_id = p.main_id 
           AND c.date_created BETWEEN DATE('2019-09-01') AND DATE(IF(p.to_range = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY('2019-09-01'),INTERVAL 10 DAY))
GROUP BY p.id,current_usage.date_created) AS table1
```

any would be really appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to group this by year-month. mysql has these `year()` and `month()` functions

```
SELECT sum(c.total_usage * p.price) as total_usage,
    p.id,year(c.date_created), month(c.date_created)
    FROM current_usage AS c
    INNER JOIN history AS p ON c.main_id = p.main_id 
           AND c.date_created BETWEEN DATE('2019-09-01') 
           AND DATE(IF(p.to_range = '0000-00-00 00:00:00', DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY('2019-09-01'),INTERVAL 10 DAY))
GROUP BY year(c.date_created), month(c.date_created), p.id
```

Comment: p.id appears redundant in the above , and I can't really see that this produces the desired result